# String Manipulation in C#: deserialize JSON

Tags: c#, string, c#-3.0

Can I use a string function in C# to manipulate this string;

```
"[{\"param\":\"Update Payment\",\"value\":\"50.00\"}]"
```

I want to get at all times the string in position `"Update Payment"` as well as the value in `"50.00"`

Comment: It would be wise to accept some of the answers to your questions..

Comment: I dont understand your last sentence where you state what you are looking for. But from the sounds if it, you are looking for some regular expression behaviour.

Comment: @Jamie Yes, I didn't answer because of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this appear to be JSON why don't you use a JSON deserializer ? http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx for example.

Comment: it is JSON. how do I use deserializer against this object?

Comment: @Jamaicas: follow the example in the link I sent in the reply.